# Can't update UIButton image

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

I'm going nuts over here. I have a button that takes a check mark as its image. I've simplified my code down to a simple user action of clicking the button, which should replace the background image. But yet it the image won't change.

```
- (IBAction)sendResults:(UIButton *)sender
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox"];
    if (image){
        NSLog(@"image is good");
        [self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"problem");
    }
}
```

Here is the console output: `image is good`

And yes, there is an outlet to the checkbox. I've verified that it is correct.

I even tried setting the image to nil, but it STILL didn't go away!

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure about self.resultsCheckBox reference is connected if your button simple create in nib file?

Comment: Well, when I look in the storyboard and right click on the button, it shows a reference to the correct UIButton in the .m file. Is there another way that I can prove this link is correct?

Comment: @usr55410: check Bhavesh's answer.. and make sure your image in png not jpg.

Comment: Are you set any default image in Button for Normal state?

Comment: @Reformer - yes, there is a default image. When I remove it and set the image in `viewDidLoad` my problem goes away. But this shouldn't be the case, right? What am I missing?

Comment: The default image behavior like overlap on background image. Due to overlapping your background image getting changed but it hidden.

Comment: Will you please post that as a solution. I would never have figured that out. Thanks!

Comment: @use55410 check my new answer.,,,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are changing image of your UIButton

> ```
> UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked_checkbox.png"];
> [btn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
> ```

before changing background

> [btn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox.png"]
>   forState:UIControlStateNormal];

You should only Change setBackgroundImage: or setImage: at a time.

BackgroundImage is below Image Layer of UIButton

Comment: That was it. Another way to say this that I simply used the function `setBackgroundImage` when I should have used `setImage`.  Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to change both default and background image. It always better to maintain single scenario for selected-unselect image, either it would be default yeah either background. The 2nd way and always preferable to set up both state images in nib.

Answer (score 0):

First include the extension (.png, .jpeg) of the image file .

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked_checkbox.png"];
```

Then try

```
if (image)
 {
    NSLog(@"image is good");

    if(self.resultsCheckBox){
        [self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.resultsCheckBox];
     }
    else{
       NSLog(@"self.resultsCheckBox not found");
    }

    } else
    {
       NSLog(@"problem");
    }
```

**or try these all options**

```
[self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
[self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; 
[self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateDisabled]; 
[self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected]; 
[self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateApplication]; 
[self.resultsCheckBox setBackgroundImage:image forState: UIControlStateReserved];
```

Comment: That was a good idea. Unfortunately, I still have the same result.

Comment: @usr55410: what is your resultsCheckBox current state? is it normal or selected?

Comment: check button reference is it outlet?

Comment: also set image as 'nil' before you assign new image.

Answer (score 0):

What I had to do is to put a UIImage behind the (transparent) UIButton and is this image that I could change with:
[self.imageView setImage:chosenImage];
[self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];

Hope it helps.